# Python bindings not loaded issue in Rstudio

Tags: r, tensorflow, rstudio

I want to use `Tensorflow` package for R in Windows.

Done with Python 3.5.x installation from python.org and have installed the `Tensorflow` R package from `devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")`as per the official source https://rstudio.github.io/tensorflow/

I know I am not setting the environment variable in the right way in the windows and/or in the `sys.setenv` function of R.

Above link says it should be set to `Sys.setenv(TENSORFLOW_PYTHON="/usr/local/bin/python")`.

See below the location of my Python35 folder which includes all the python stuff including the `tensorflow` library downloaded from the python side:

**Python35 folder location**:C:\Users\rgupta6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35

**tensorflow folder location**: C:\Users\rgupta6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow

Code I used:

```
Sys.setenv(TENSORFLOW_PYTHON="C:\\Users\\rgupta6\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35")
Sys.setenv(TENSORFLOW_PYTHON="C:\\Users\\rgupta6\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow")
```

I use `library(tensorflow)` and get no error.

Then I use `sess = tf$Session()` and get an error:

> Error in initialize_python(required_module) : Installation of Python not found, Python bindings not loaded*.

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting errors such as:

1. > Error in initialize_python(required_module) : Installation of Python not found, Python bindings not loaded
2. > Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found
3. > Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
   >   C:\Users\rgupta6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe
4. Some error related to file does not exist

While trying to make `Tensorflow` package to work in Rstudio, the problem is with your environment variable in Windows.

What you need to do is:

1. From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
2. Choose Properties from the context menu.
3. Click the Advanced system settings link.
4. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit.
5. A new pop up will open. Variable name will remain Path. We will change the Variable value to the location of the folder where your **tensorflow** folder is located. Find it.

For e.g. I changed its value to:
**C:\Users\rgupta6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow**

6. Close all remaining windows. Open Rstudio, and run your "Hello World" program to see if your tensorflow works fine in R:

`library(tensorflow)
sess = tf$Session()
hello <- tf$constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess$run(hello)`

Comment: @ rajesh: I am getting the same error, in a server environment. How can I make tensorflow to work with R in a server environment? Thanks.